# Doctrine: Is there a way to handle "postRemove" only after the transaction gets commited?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to delete a file related to given entity after the entity itself is removed from the database. Doctrine's "postRemove" event seems perfect for that, except when the removal happens inside a transaction. If I rollback the transaction after removing the entity - the files will get deleted but the entity will remain in the database.

The project I'm working on is a very big one and this entity is widely used. Often it also gets removed through "cascade=remove", so the "you can just not use events and do it manually every time" soultion would be kind of a headache to implement.

An example case:

```
$img = new Image();
$img->setFileName('test.jpg');
$em->persist($img);
$em->flush();

$em->beginTransaction();
$em->remove($img);
$em->flush();
$em->rollback();
```

The event itself would be like:

```
public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $entity = $args->getObject();
    $em = $args->getObjectManager();

    if ($entity instanceof Image && file_exists($entity->getFileName())) {
        unlink($entity->getFileName());
    }
}
```

After executing that code the "test.jpg" file will be deleted, but the entity will still remain.

What I want to achieve is: on rollback both the file and the entity remain and on commit both of them are removed.

Comment: lifecycle events are called on flush (when the database receives the delete call, in this case). I would assume, that you probably have to decorate the entity manager, and on flush, you would keep a list of files to remove, and actually remove them when commit is called. you probably have to check, if the entitymanager is in a transaction, when flush is called. on commit, obviously, you have to check if the transaction failed or was successful (that can happen still)